# Django OperationalError no such table:

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, operationalerror

I created a profile models: This is the code

```
 class NPC_profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ID = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    학번 = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

and views

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST["password"] == request.POST["repassword"]:
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=request.POST["username"], password=request.POST["password"])
            ID = request.POST["ID"]
            학번 = request.POST["학번"]
            profile = NPC_profile(user=user, ID=ID, 학번=학번)
            profile.save()
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('list')
        return render(request, 'NPC/signup.html')
    return render(request, 'NPC/signup.html')
```

but

```
appear OperationalError at /NPC/signup/
no such table: NPC_npc_profile
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Di you make migrations and migrate your database?

Comment: Yes, I did python manage.py makemigrations, python manage.py migrate

Comment: sorry for answering late